# Unable to compile [MinGW]

Tags: c++, linker, program-entry-point

I try to run this code, but I encounter the error as shown above . My first assumption is the linker file is incorrect. If my linker file is incorrect, then what should I change for the linker file? 
My second assumption is I set a wrong path to the linker file. Currently, I set my path to C:\Apps\MinGW\bin. If my path is wrong, then what should I set my path to?

Comment: For future reference, consider pasting text rather than images of text, because images make it really difficult for answers to quote bits of your code and output. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) if you have formatting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got the idea that the entry point should be called `run`. It should be called [`main`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function), just rename it:

```
int main () 
{
    ....
}
```

That particular error message is a bit misleading to the untrained eye (explaining it goes further down the rabbit hole than I'd like to go) but that's essentially what that one means in this context.

Comment: I change run to main, but it still does not work.

Comment: @BarryP There's no reason it shouldn't work. Did you type `main` correctly? Did you save the file before rebuilding? Try a clean build?

Comment: What do you mean by try a clean build? Sorry I'm new.

Comment: @BarryP Delete your output .o files and intermediate output files and build again.

Comment: I delete .o files, and the result's still the same

Answer (score 1):

I think, `main` is required for every CPP program. 
Whenever you start compiling your program, the complier will find this function first and of course your program doesn't contain this.

So, try changing the function from `run` to `main`

Hope it works!

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work.

Comment: Where did you install MinGW ?

Comment: It run perfect fine with my other projects, but it does not work on this specific project.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int run()
{

}
```

to

```
int main()
{

}
```